# how to get all nested div heights using jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors

How to get all heights from the div's nested inside the "GO" div:

```
<div id="GO" style="max-height: 100px;">
<div style="height: 569px;"></div>
<div style="height: 469px;"></div>
<div style="height: 269px;"></div>
<div style="height: 69px;"></div>
<div style="height: 169px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="STOP">
</div>
```

I tried using this code

```
var vales;
vales =$("#GO div").height();
//planB
vales =$("#GO").height();
```

But it didn't solve my problem

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see you have many children divs in the parent one so you need to iterate over the children to get each of them. You can create a blank array and with use of each loop you can push the height values in it but i would suggest you to use `.map()` method which creates an array of returned values.

You can use `.map().get()`:

```js
var vales = $("#GO div").map(function(){
    // return $(this).css('height'); // only if you want applied css values with 'px' etc.
    return $(this).height();
}).get();

$('pre').html(JSON.stringify(vales));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
<div id="GO" style="max-height: 100px;">
<div style="height: 569px;"></div>
<div style="height: 469px;"></div>
<div style="height: 269px;"></div>
<div style="height: 69px;"></div>
<div style="height: 169px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="STOP">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To iterate the children div's and get the height value, you can do something like this:

```
$("#GO > div").each(function() {
    $(this).height();
});
```

Comment: That is correct but you have to use the values in each iteration currently it just does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this ?

```
$("#GO").children().each(function(){
    $(this).height();
});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10819051)

Comment: please explain me easy

Comment: I answered faster than Daniel and it's not matter that I think. what the problem?